# Using GetRows on Recordset object returns no rows

Tags: vba, recordset

I am trying to load a recordset into an array.  I am using the following code:

```
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT id FROM TABLE1")  
bankacid = rst.GetRows()  
rst.Close  
i = UBound(bankacid, 2)   
MsgBox i + 1
```

This returns no rows.  If I use "bankacid = rst.getrows(5)"  it works.

I am very new to VBA and would very much 
appreciate someone pointing out what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to take a step back and say why you want an array, after all, a DAO recorset is much more functional than an array. If an array is really necessary, use ADODB. If you just want to refer to fields and rows, use Move, MoveFirst, MoveLast, MoveNext, MovePrevious and either the name of the field (column) or the ordinal position (.Field(3).

Comment: Thanks v much above works well and is a much better that what I was trying to do.  I am still a bit confused as to why the original code would only work if i selected the amount of records to populate e.g. "getrows(5)" and not when i used "getrows()" from what I have read getrows() should select all records??

Comment: I think you are thinking of ADO GetRows, which retrieves all rows. DAO Getrows is a different thing : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/129856